# Optimize For Each Loop

Tags: optimization, excel, vba

When I was initially building this code I searched heavily for other solutions but was not able to find anything that worked.

I have a spreadsheet that I work with daily whose content also changes daily (as do the number of rows). Note that I use named ranges for this code (such as "Rules1); the ranges are deleted and re-named each day so I don't have to keep defining the number of rows in the code. There are about 5,000 rows in the spreadsheet, though it will grow over time.

The code works beautifully - but slowly. I'm looking for a good way to speed it up. The purpose of this code is to replace the text "ZZZ" with "C1" or whatever row that line happens to be on. For example, I might have a string such as `OR(LEFT(ZZZ,6)="SAMPLE",LEFT(ZZZ,12)="SALES SAMPLE")` and I need to replace the "ZZZ" with "C2420" because that's what row this line is on today. Note that the above is not a formula - in this stage of the code it lacks the "=", which I insert later.

```
Sub Replace_ZZZ()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Dim Rules1 As Range
    Set Rules1 = Range("Rules1")
    Dim Rules2 As Range
    Set Rules2 = Range("Rules2")
    Dim Rules3 As Range
    Set Rules3 = Range("Rules3")
    Dim Rules4 As Range
    Set Rules4 = Range("Rules4")
    Dim Rules5 As Range
    Set Rules5 = Range("Rules5")
    Dim RulesAll As Range
    Set RulesAll = Range("RulesAll")

    Workbooks("POVA Daily Reporter.xlsm").Worksheets("Paste Daily Data").Select
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    Cells.Copy
    Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("G2").Select

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim Cell As Variant
    On Error Resume Next

    For Each Cell In Rules1
        Call Cell.Replace("ZZZ", Cell.OffSet(0, -4).Address)
        Call Cell.Replace("zzz", Cell.OffSet(0, -4).Address)
    Next Cell

    For Each Cell In Rules2
        Call Cell.Replace("ZZZ", Cell.OffSet(0, -5).Address)
        Call Cell.Replace("zzz", Cell.OffSet(0, -5).Address)
    Next Cell

    For Each Cell In Rules3
        Call Cell.Replace("ZZZ", Cell.OffSet(0, -6).Address)
        Call Cell.Replace("zzz", Cell.OffSet(0, -6).Address)
    Next Cell

    For Each Cell In Rules4
        Call Cell.Replace("ZZZ", Cell.OffSet(0, -7).Address)
        Call Cell.Replace("zzz", Cell.OffSet(0, -7).Address)
    Next Cell

    For Each Cell In Rules5
        Call Cell.Replace("ZZZ", Cell.OffSet(0, -8).Address)
        Call Cell.Replace("zzz", Cell.OffSet(0, -8).Address)
    Next Cell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Sheet.Calculate

End Sub
```

Comment: `Call Cell.Replace("ZZZ", Cell.OffSet(0, -4).Address)` I don't understand this line. Also are you aware that the replace can be done with MatchCase as `False` or compare method as `vbTextCompare` so that you don't have to replace `ZZZ` and `zzz`? You don't need the 2nd line everytime

Comment: Hi Siddharth, thank you for your comments. I have to confess I don't understand that line of code either, but it works consistently. Thanks for the heads up about the case difference. Any other thoughts about how to make this faster, though?

Comment: May I see your workbook? If yes, then you may upload it in wikisend.com and share the link here

Comment: I certainly appreciate such an offer to help more extensively. Unfortunately it contains some confidential customer information that I would be unable to share, and it would take me a long time to mine through it to clear out such information. Thank you, though!

Comment: The problem is you are looping through every cell in 5 ranges and doing a replace which will be slow. I was hoping to see if there was a better way to solve your problem. Anyways, another tip: Set the calculation to manual before the code and then back to automatic after the code is run.

Comment: Manual calculation helped but it is still slow, unfortunately.

Comment: Well this is the max I can do for you without seeing your workbook and actually understanding what you are trying to do :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going through each cell individually, use relative references so you can apply `Replace` to all cells at once:

```
Range("Rules1").Replace "ZZZ", "INDIRECT(""R[-4]C"", FALSE)"
Range("Rules2").Replace "ZZZ", "INDIRECT(""R[-5]C"", FALSE)"
Range("Rules3").Replace "ZZZ", "INDIRECT(""R[-6]C"", FALSE)"
Range("Rules4").Replace "ZZZ", "INDIRECT(""R[-7]C"", FALSE)"
Range("Rules5").Replace "ZZZ", "INDIRECT(""R[-8]C"", FALSE)"
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, rdhs! Unfortunately, the code you suggested did not work. For example, in row 18 it created this string `ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(INDIRECT("R[-4]C", FALSE),7)))` when it should be `ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(C10,7)))`

Comment: Those two formulas should give you the same result, though.

Comment: Sorry, there may not be enough information to see the whole picture, my fault. "Rules1" is a named range of (in this example) Range("G2:G3952"), but since it can change every day, I rename the range each day so that it includes all new data. Does that make a difference?

Comment: What I mean is that when you actually make it into a formula, Excel will treat `INDIRECT("R[-4]C", FALSE)` just as if it had seen `C10`.

Comment: I thought that's the way it would work. For some reason it's not seeing it as `C18` (note that the cell example I gave was `C18`; could have been `C2952`, depends on which cell we choose).

Comment: That's difficult to tell since it's not giving me the actual cell reference. It's just evaluating some cell to False when the actual result should be True. Sorry, really challenging to give details without sharing the spreadsheet, which unfortunately I'm not permitted to do.